# Ubuntu MATE 17.10 freezes

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-mate

Today I installed Ubuntu MATE 17.10 on my old HP Mini. Everything is working perfectly fine except one thing. When I move my mouse to the bottom edge Ubuntu freezes. Neither mouse nor keyboard reacts then. Any clue on the fix?
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I did not have that problem on 17.04

Comment: same problem as you